# How to clear of contents of string in Arduino?

Tags: string

Currently I convert the characters in `char received[20]` to string using `String randomString(received)` and I am able to display it using `Serial.println(randomString)`. After displaying the string, I would like to know the easiest way to clear out its contents.

Comment: Have a look at the related question at stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632846/clearing-a-char-array-c ...

Comment: Why are you converting a char array to a String just to print it? Do you realise just how bad that is for the poor little Arduino? http://hacking.majenko.co.uk/the-evils-of-arduino-strings

Answer (score 2):

In C and C++ a null terminated array of characters **is** a string (although not a String). Many routines for reading input terminate the result with a null as does an assignment like"

```
char foo[] = "This is a string.";
```

All you would need to do to "clear" this string is to assign a null to the first character. For example:

```
foo[0] = '\0';
```

Comment: This clears only the first byte. With `= { 0 };` everything is cleared.

Comment: For C (null terminated) strings, if the first character is a null, then the string is empty or clear. Functionally that solves the problem, but if there are security concerns then you are right that the whole string should be cleared.

Answer (score 0):

First version with conversion from char[] to Arduino String class:

```
char received[20];
...
// Some code that assigns received
...
String randomString(received); 
Serial.println(randomString);

// Clear string
randomString = "";
```

Second version without the Arduino String class:

```
char received[20];
...
// Some code that assigns received
...
Serial.println(received);

// Empty received buffer
received[0] = 0;
```

And third version where the buffer is cleared:

```
char received[20];
...
// Some code that assigns received
...
Serial.println(received);

// Clear received buffer
memset(received, 0, sizeof(received));
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Although an old question, I thought I would chime in. If I took the time to understand the question properly, I believe you wanted to clear the contents of the String and not the char array. This may help those who wanted to empty a string for other reasons.

```
String randomString(received);
Serial.println(randomString);
randomString.clear(); // This will clear the string
```

It should be noted that for outputing, there was no need to convert to string first if that was all that was required, because println will prefer a char array anyway.

Again String has a `.clear()` method for those who reached this page via web search.

Update:
It has been pointed out thanks to @VE7JRO in the comments, that the `clear` methods availablity is not universal. The ESP devices with Arduino compatibile core libraries do have it, as may others. But AVR devices such as the UNO do not. Which I have confirmed.

A revised version to suit all cases where the `.clear` method is unavailable.

```cpp
String randomString(received);
Serial.println(randomString);
randomString = ""; // This will clear the string
```

Comment: Arduino IDE 1.8.9 says this about the `clear()` function "'class String' has no member named 'clear'". What version of the IDE / other software are you using?

Comment: @VE7RJO Using platformio, it shows the method. Which I have alreay used in code. It may depend on whether using AVR or the ESP's but it is certainly present on the ESP8266.

Comment: The OP's question "title" mentions "Arduino", which as far as I know is not an ESP8266. Perhaps another Arduino user with a newer version of the IDE could confirm / deny whether this woks or not.

Comment: @VE7JRO Have revised after testing. Thanks.